# Reverse proxy RewriteRule doesn't redirect to /home the same way the target does

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have the following `.htaccess` code which reverse proxies the site from another URL.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?objecta-design\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://objecta.i-coop.de%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

And this works, it redirects me from [www.objecta-design.com](http://www.objecta-design.com) to https://objecta.i-coop.de while keeping the original URL. The problem is that if you navigate to https://objecta.i-coop.de it will automatically redirect you to /home and this does not happen when I navigate from [www.objecta-design.com](http://www.objecta-design.com)

I know that while in the original objecta.i-coop.de we do a 302 redirect to /home but this somehow is not done on the Rewrite rule.

Comment: I introduced the correct terminology of "reverse proxy" into your question since that is what your `[P]` rewrite rule is actually doing.  It shouldn't be described as "a redirect that keeps the URL"

Comment: Do you have access to the server config? What is the actual response you are getting, with full HTTP response headers? How are you performing the redirect to `/home` (what is the logic involved)? There's no obvious reason why a redirect does not occur (without perhaps seeing the logic involved in the redirect). The "problem" that can occur (unless `ProxyPassReverse` is set in the server config) is that the target server issues a redirect to itself and "breaks" the proxy.

Comment: Yes I think that's exactly what happens. The code does some logic to find the homepage (this is configurable by the user). It then redirects itself to the whatever the users configures as the default page. Do you know why this breaks the proxy? and if somehow I can prevent it from breaking?

Comment: By "breaking the proxy" I mean the user is redirected to the target domain (ie. `objecta.i-coop.de` in your case), thus the user breaks out of the proxy connection and the target domain is exposed - the redirect still occurs. Is that really what you are seeing? This requires access to the server config - this cannot be resolved in `.htaccess`, since it requires that `ProxyPassReverse` be set (as mentioned above).